# Unable to read registry from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry

I have a requirement where I need to use a batch file to perform certain tasks depending on some registry values. I am able to run and achieve my goal if I run the batch file manually. But if the batch is run using some executable it is not able to get the registry values. It reads all the registry values as empty. I  don't see any particular reason for this behavior. The actual requirement is to run this batch file as part of self extracting executable. I tried it launching using C# application, still no luck. Any ideas? what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Post the code, otherwise this post is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Most likely cause: the executable is 32-bit, so it is launching a 32-bit instance of `cmd.exe` to run the batch file, so you're seeing the [32-bit view of the registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx) rather than the 64-bit view.  Something along the lines of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27093204/886887) might resolve the problem.

Comment: @Harry Thanks. That was the actual reason. Though the executable was 64 bit it is still trying to read the 32 bit registry. I had to force it to read 64 bit registry.

Comment: If the executable that launched the batch file really is 64-bit, you should have wound up with the 64-bit command interpreter running the batch file, and so it should behave the same way as when run from the command line.  If that isn't the case, you should find out why - it might indicate a more serious problem.

Answer (score 0):

Elevate the permissions on the executable i.e Run as Administrator

Comment: I tried running as Administrator, it didn't work. When I run the batch using command prompt it simply able to run without needing Administrator privilege. So this doesn't seem to be the issue.