# Facing Error while scheduling SSIS package from oracle source to MSSQL destination

Tags: oracle, ssis

> "Code: 0xC0208449 Source: Data Flow Task ADO NET Source [2] Description: ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection {D90365A5-9C3E-4197-AD2F-D17E994537BD} with the following error message: System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater."

I'm having a scenario to load data from oracle to ssms using SSIS,  while i try to run that package manually I'm facing no issues I'm able to load data successfully ,but when i try to schedule the package using .bat file,  then I'm facing above error ,please help me figure this out

The oracle version is 12c and 64bit

Comment: This might be an issue of running your package in x86 vs. x64 - do you have both Oracle client versions (x86 and x64) installed?

Comment: No I'm having only 64bit in the system I've verified with comps.xml file under<DEP_LIST>  plat = "NT_AMD64"

Comment: Maybe [How to run a batch file in 64 bit mode ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27090734/205233) helps.